# Generic Excel Generator function for EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, epplus

How would one build a generic EPPlus Spreadsheet function for your LINQ Queries?

UPDATE: The need was specifically for an ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is now a more simple way to achieve this using the LoadFromCollection method.

```
public void ExportToExcel(IEnumerable<Employee> employees, FileInfo targetFile)
{
    using (var excelFile = new ExcelPackage(targetFile))
    {
        var worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(Collection: employees, PrintHeaders: true);
        excelFile.Save();
    }
}
```

Example taken from here: http://gruffcode.com/2013/10/30/simple-excel-export-with-epplus/

Answer (score 22):

All I did was create a generic function that accepts a List. I use reflection to get a list of properties, which will become our Column heading. FInally, I simply let EPPlus do all the heavy lifting.

```
void ListToExcel<T>(List<T> query)
    {            
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        { 
            //Create the worksheet
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Result");

            //get our column headings
            var t = typeof(T);
            var Headings = t.GetProperties();
            for (int i = 0; i < Headings.Count(); i++)
            {

                ws.Cells[1, i+1].Value = Headings[i].Name;
            }

            //populate our Data
            if (query.Count() > 0)
            {
                ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(query);
            }

            //Format the header
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:BZ1"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;                      //Set Pattern for the background to Solid
                rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189));  //Set color to dark blue
                rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
            }

            //Write it back to the client
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```