# export to Excel from a list with EPPLUS

Tags: c#, excel, list, sql-server-2008, epplus

i´m trying to export a list to Excel in c# with EPPLUS, when i execute the program don´t give me errors, but when i open the Excel i see that are not the correct data, he put the name of the projet+the name of the object as many times as objects have the list:
[image]

The code of the object:

```
class Stock
        {
            public string Nif;
            public string Proveedor;
            public string Coodigo;
            public string descripcion;
            public string Catalogo;
            public string Estadistico;
            public decimal StockOn;

        }
```

and when thes list(lstStock) is filled i create an Excel and use the option loadfromcollection  :

```
        System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo("D:\\stock_termos.xlsx");
            if (f.Exists) f.Delete();
            using (ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage(f))
            {   
                ExcelWorksheet hoja = ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TOTAL OBSOLETOS");
                hoja.Cells[1, 1].Value = "NIF"; ;
                hoja.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Proveedor";
                hoja.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Código";
                hoja.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Descripción";
                hoja.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Catálogo";
                hoja.Cells[1, 6].Value = "Cod.Estadístico";
                hoja.Cells[1, 7].Value = "Stock On";
                hoja.Cells[2, 1].LoadFromCollection(lstStock);
            }
```

The cuestión is that when i debug the aplication in VisualStudio i can see the list is correctly filled:

[image]

So i think the error is when i try to export the data to Excel, with the LoadFromCollection method, but i can´t se what is wrong, please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic Excel Generator function for EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511690/generic-excel-generator-function-for-epplus)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of EPPlus are you using?  I ask because I am surprised it does not throw an error as it does with 4.1.0 which is currently the latest.  Maybe an older version is more forgiving.

But to answer you question, if you look at the signature of the final overload of `LoadFromCollection` that is eventually called you will see this:

```
public ExcelRangeBase LoadFromCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> Collection, bool PrintHeaders, TableStyles TableStyle, BindingFlags memberFlags, MemberInfo[] Members)
```

Notice that Epplus is only looking at `MemberInfos` and not a `Fields` which is what you object is using.  If you change `Stock` object to this:

```
class Stock
{
    public string Nif { get; set; }
    public string Proveedor { get; set; }
    public string Coodigo { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public string Catalogo { get; set; }
    public string Estadistico { get; set; }
    public decimal StockOn { get; set; }
}
```

You should see results.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, i don´t know why i don´t put the {get;set}  i always do at this way.
The versión of EPPLUS is 4.0.4.0

Comment: @Ion, no big deal, happens to us all sometimes :).  Interesting about version 4.0.4 not throwing an exception.  Its actually better that 4.1 does so at least you know something went wrong at testing.