# Having problems at exporting gridview paging enable to excel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Having problems at exporting gridview paging enable to excel , i can't export to excel because it accuse an error and i couldn't fix it yet , so I'm here to look for some help

```
        protected void Sqldata_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Sqldata.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            Sqldata.DataSource= SqlDataSource1 ;
            Sqldata.DataBind();
            DataBind();

        }
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(System.Web.UI.Control control)
        {
            //confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the
            //specified ASP.NET server control at run time.
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=register.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "applicantion/excel";
            StringWriter ad = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter sd = new HtmlTextWriter(ad);
            Sqldata.RenderControl(sd);
            Response.Write(ad.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: What version of excel is on machine?  Can you write a xlsx instead of xls?

Comment: its 2016 excel but even with xls or xlsx it doesn't work ,xlsx it download an invalid file that i can't open , xls it download a file that i can open but does not export data in all pages and appear that error before+

Comment: @ sr28 this "System.InvalidOperationException: 'RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render ();' "

Comment: @sr28 can u help me ?

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: @VDWWD I'm still having problems at downloading the excelsheet with paging there

Comment: That is why you need to work with the source data and not the GridView contents.

Comment: @VDWWD and do you know any post in this community that can help me with this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293207/5836671 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39513057/5836671