# Trouble exporting gridview to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

When I try to export my gridview results as an .xls it is only exporting it as an .aspx webpage. I am not sure what I am missing here. I think there is something wrong in my aspx.cs page but can't find it. It might be in my "ExportGridToExcel" method. I have tried to do some simple googling for other people running into the same issue and only found one article but it did not help me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace crifaccess
{
    public partial class Application : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        private SqlConnection con;
        private SqlCommand com;
        private string constr, query;
        private void connection()
        {
            constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["getconn"].ToString();
            con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Bindgrid();
            }

            }

        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {

        }

        private void Bindgrid()
        {
            connection();
            query = "ApplicationPageSSN";
            com = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            GridView2.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }

        protected void ExcelExport_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExportGridToExcel();
        }

        private void ExportGridToExcel()
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.Charset = "";
            string FileName = "CRIF" + DateTime.Now+".xls";
            StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filname=" + FileName);
            GridView2.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
            GridView2.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            GridView2.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
            Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }






    }

    }
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293207/5836671) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39513057/5836671). All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: If your data is just column headings and rows of data, you could get away with exporting it as CSV ? Excel will open that, albeit with no formatting.